# how to draw tilegram/hexagon map in R

Tags: r, dictionary, leaflet

I'm referring to [this article](http://rpubs.com/bhaskarvk/electoral-Map-2016) on US tilegram in R. However, I don't know what pre-processing is needed on the df in order to turn it into a hexagon map or tilegram. The `sf_NPR1to1` passed to leaflet in the example seems to be a sf object.

For a simple data frame with state name and measure attached to each state, what preprocessing is needed to turn it into a tilegram?

```
df <- data.frame(state=c("New York","New Jersey","California"), num=c(10,20,30))
```

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: the reproducible example is in the link

Comment: The best approach is that you help others to help you. In this case, as the example is a step by step guide, you should explain what you tried but didn't work. This is also recommended on the help pages I linked to in my first comment.

Comment: the example, though step-by-step, started with a special data object. what i attempted, listed in the question, is a generic data frame that look nothing like the sf_NPR1to1 in the example.

Answer (score 2):

having had to solve this problem before, I thought I would post a more general solution. For the US and the US there are many existing ESRI shapefiles which can be used, but there may be cases where you are not looking at these countries, you may want to follow these steps.

The approach taken is to create a tessellated grid of hexagons that are equal to the average size of the country then assign a country to the grid point that is closest to the centre of the country. This treats it as an optimisation problem.  The really clever stuff is the [Munkres 'Hungarian' algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) found in the `clue` package.

I created a package to solve this [here](https://lajh87.gitlab.io/makeTilegram/index.html) where for example, Africa it is as simple as:

```
# Install package
if(!"makeTilegram" %in% installed.packages()[,"Package"])
  devtools::install_git("https://gitlab.com/lajh87/makeTilegram")

# Load required packages
require(makeTilegram)
require(rworldmap)

#  Load simple map (without islands) from the `rworldmap` package
data("countriesCoarseLessIslands") 

# Subset for Africa and remove NAs in the regions
afr <- countriesCoarseLessIslands[which(!is.na(countriesCoarseLessIslands@data$REGION) &  
                                          countriesCoarseLessIslands@data$REGION=="Africa"),]


tileGram <- makeTilegram(afr) # Make a Tilegram
plot(tileGram)
```

If for any reason you cannot install the package from my gitlab page you can just source the following code:

```
## Helper functions
deg2rad <- function(deg) {(deg * pi) / (180)} # Function to convert degrees to radians (trigonemetry)

hex_side <- function(area) {(3^0.25)*sqrt(2*(area/9))} # Get the length of a side of hexagon for a given area

hex_area <- function(side) ((3*sqrt(3))/2*side) # Get the area of a hexagon given its side length

# Function to draw a hexagon
draw_hex <- function(area=hex_area(1), offset_x = 0, offset_y = 0, id=1, tessellate=F){
  side_length <- hex_side(area)
  A <- sin(deg2rad(30)) * side_length
  B <- sin(deg2rad(60)) * side_length
  C <- side_length

  (x <- c(0, 0, B, 2*B, 2*B, B) + (offset_x*B*2) + ifelse(tessellate == T,  B, 0))
  (y <- c(A+C, A, 0, A, A+C, 2*C) + (offset_y*(A+C)))


  sp::Polygons(list(sp::Polygon(coords = matrix(c(x,y),ncol=2),hole = F)),ID=id)
}

# Function to get the sum of the area of SpatialPolygons
getArea <-  function(x) {
  getAreaPolygons = function(x) {
    holes = unlist(lapply(x@Polygons, function(x) x@hole))
    areas = unlist(lapply(x@Polygons, function(x) x@area))
    area = ifelse(holes, -1, 1) * areas
    area
  }
  sum(unlist(lapply(x@polygons, getAreaPolygons)))
}

# The average area of SpatialPolygons
getAvgArea <- function(x){
  l <- length(x)
  avgArea <- getArea(x)/l
  return(avgArea)
}

# Draw a grid of hexagon tiles
draw_hexTiles <- function(area, offset_x_start=0, offset_x_end=4, offset_y_start=0, offset_y_end =4){
  grid <- expand.grid(offset_x_start:offset_x_end, offset_y_start:offset_y_end)
  grid$tessellate <- grid[,2] %% 2 == 0

  hexes <- sp::SpatialPolygons(lapply(1:nrow(grid), function(i){
    draw_hex(area, offset_x = grid[i,1], offset_y = grid[i,2], id =i, tessellate = grid[i,3])

  }))

  names(grid) <- c("offset_x", "offset_y", "tessellate")

  grid <- data.frame(id = 1:nrow(grid),grid)

  sp::SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(hexes, grid)
}

#' Draw hexagon tiles
#'
#' Draw a grid of tessellated hexagons over the bounding box of a SpatialPolygons object
#'
#' @param x An sp object
#' @param cellsize The size of the hexagons, if left blank then will take the average area of the polygons in the SpatialPolygons data.frame
#'
#' @return A SpatialPolygonsDataFrame of tessellated hexagons covering the bounding box of a SpatialPolygons
#' @export
#'
#' @examples
#' require(rworldmap);
#' data("countriesCoarseLessIslands") #  Load simple map without islands
#' afr <- countriesCoarseLessIslands[which(!is.na(countriesCoarseLessIslands@data$REGION) &
#'                                          countriesCoarseLessIslands@data$REGION=="Africa"),]
#' afr <- sp::spTransform(afr, CRS("+init=EPSG:32663")) # Project to equidistant grid
#' plot(hex_tiles(afr)[afr,]) # Clip to original shape and plot
hex_tiles <- function(x, cellsize=NULL){

  if(is.null(cellsize)) cellsize <- getAvgArea(x)*.9

  b <- sp::bbox(x)
  dx <- b["x", "max"] - b["x", "min"]
  dy <- b["y", "max"] - b["y", "min"]

  C <- hex_side(cellsize)
  A <- sin(deg2rad(30)) * C
  B <- sin(deg2rad(60)) * C

  hexAcross <- ceiling(dx/(B*2))
  hexUp <- ceiling(dy/((A+C)))

  offset_x_start <- floor(b["x", "min"]/(B*2))
  offset_y_start <- floor(b["y", "min"]/((A+C)))
  offset_x_end <- offset_x_start + hexAcross
  offset_y_end <- offset_y_start + hexUp

  hex_grid <- draw_hexTiles(cellsize, offset_x_start, offset_x_end, offset_y_start, offset_y_end)
  sp::proj4string(hex_grid) <- sp::proj4string(x)
  return(hex_grid)
}

#' Make a Tilegram
#'
#' Function to make a tilegram from a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame.
#' It draws a grid of hexagons over the bounding box of the SpatialPolygonsDataFrame and
#' then uses the 'Hungarian' algorithm found in the `clue` package to match hexagons to
#' Polygons by minimising the distance between the centre of the hexagon and the centroid of the polygon.
#'
#' @param sp A SpatialPolygonDataFrame
#' @param cellsize The cellsize of the hexagons. If left blank then it will be based on the average size of the polygons in sp
#'
#' @return A SpatialPolygonsDataFrame projected to EPSG:32663 equidistant grid
#' @export
#'
#' @examples
#' require(rworldmap);
#' data("countriesCoarseLessIslands") #  Load simple map without islands
#' afr <- countriesCoarseLessIslands[which(!is.na(countriesCoarseLessIslands@data$REGION) &
#'                                          countriesCoarseLessIslands@data$REGION=="Africa"),]
#' tileGram <- makeTilegram(afr)
#' plot(tileGram)
makeTilegram <- function(sp,cellsize=NULL){

  sp <- sp::spTransform(sp, sp::CRS("+init=EPSG:32663")) # Project to equidistant grid

  tiles <- hex_tiles(sp,cellsize) # Create hexagon tiles
  tiles <- tiles[sp,]

  pts <- rgeos::gCentroid(sp,byid = T) # Get centroid of polygons
  pts <- sp::SpatialPointsDataFrame(pts, data.frame(pt_id = row.names(pts), stringsAsFactors = F))

  tileCentroids <- rgeos::gCentroid(tiles, T)
  tileCentroids <- sp::SpatialPointsDataFrame(tileCentroids, data.frame(id = row.names(tileCentroids),stringsAsFactors = F))

  distance <- rgeos::gDistance(tileCentroids, pts, byid=T)
  tile_pref <- t(apply(distance,1, function(x) rank(x,ties.method ="random")))

  solved <- clue::solve_LSAP(tile_pref, maximum = FALSE)
  solved_cols <- as.numeric(solved)

  newDat <- data.frame(tile_region= row.names(tile_pref), id = as.numeric(colnames(tile_pref)[solved_cols]), stringsAsFactors = F)

  newTiles <- tiles
  newTiles@data <- plyr::join(newTiles@data, newDat, by="id")
  newTiles <- newTiles[!is.na(newTiles$tile_region),]

  return(newTiles)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The special object comes from the `tilegramsR` package. Install it using `install.packages('tilegramsR')`.